# How do I use a Iterable on 'this' when extending a Collection?

Tags: java, generics

How do I solve this error? I tried just `this`, and `(Article) this`, and `super.iterable()`, but nothing seems to work. Only types of `Article` will ever be added to this queue. Java 1.7.0_03.

```
[javac] C:\cygwin\home\Chloe\Queue.java:26: error: incompatible types
[javac]             for (Article a: (Iterable) this) {
[javac]                             ^
[javac]   required: Article
[javac]   found:    Object
```

Here is the source code.

```
public class Queue<T> extends ArrayDeque {

public int words() {
    int words;
    for (Article a: (Iterable) this) {
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The iterator of your queue will return <strike>`T`</strike> `Object` instances, not `Article`. Your loop should go like this:

```
public int words() {
    int words;
    for (Object a: this) {
       // do something
    }
}
```

Or, if you need an article queue, declare the class this way:

```
public class Queue extends ArrayDeque<Article> {

  // this queue will store Article instances

}
```

Comment: Actually, the `ArrayDeque` contains `Objects`, it wasn't declared with a generic type, so, technically, your first example is wrong, but the second one is right ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Absolutely correct! Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: Took me 10 mins of checking to be sure :P

Comment: (posted the initial answer 10 minutes after waking up and before having the first coffee ;) )

Answer (score 2):

The queue contains Objects, it has not means to know if any item is an `Article`...

Try this

```
for (Object a: this)
```

or this

```
public class Test<T> extends ArrayDeque<T> {

    public int words() {
        int words;
        for (T a : this) {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I did that: `extends ArrayDeque<Article> {`. It worked. I also tried the `for (Object` and cast it but I liked my first way (your 2nd way) better. Wasn't using Eclipse. Eclipse would have complained loudly about that.